# mongodb: update NESTED string date to iso date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I know there are stackoverflow posts on updating mongodb sting date to iso date but i could not find how to do in nested field.
my json structure is like this:

```
{  
    "_id" : "588885445",  
    "data" : {  
        "team" : "abc",  
        "subteam" : "123",  
        "datetime" : "2018-05-20 11:47:01",  

   }  
}
```

i need to change date string to iso date. This is what I am trying but its not working.

```
var cursor = db.getCollection('log').find({}) ;  
while (cursor.hasNext()) {   
var doc = cursor.next();   
db.members.update({_id : doc._id}, {'$set' : {"data.datetime" : new ISODate('data.datetime') }});  
}
```

Comment: `new ISODate(doc.data.datetime)`. Full path and no quotes for a JavaScript object. Also `new Date(doc.data.datetime)` is the same thing as `ISODate()` is really just a shell "alias" for the same function and used to denote fields with BSON Date.

Comment: it says "Updated 0 record(s) in 617ms" but date hasnt been updated. its still string.

Comment: Read the linked answer. That is what it is there for.